How to return database data from one to another class using flutter
I cannot catch or get returned data from another class. I need to get database data and returning into another class. The codes are the following...
In test_type_controller.dart
class TestTypeController extends GetxController {

  late Database database;

  static int _count = 0;
  static int get count => _count;

  getTotal() async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    
    var result = await db.query('test_type');
    int count = result.length;

    return count;
  }
}

